# Estimating $|\int_{\beta}\exp(iz^2)\ dz|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $R > 0$ and consider a curve
$$\beta(t) = R\exp(it), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \leq t \leq \pi/4.$$
I need to show that
$$\left|\int_{\beta}\exp(iz^2)\ dz \right| \leq \frac{\pi(1-\exp(-R^2))}{4R}.$$

Attempt:
Well, I thought I will just use the ML-estimate, but I got stuck. I have calculated the length of the arc of the curve $\beta$:
$$l(\beta) = \int_0^{\pi/4}|\beta^{\prime}(t)|dt = \int_0^{\pi/4}|iR\exp(it)|\ dt = \int_0^{\pi/4}R^2\ dt = \frac{\pi R^2}{4}.$$
Now I would like to find an $M > 0$ such that $|\exp(iz^2)|$ for any $z \in \ \text{Image}\ \beta $.

We have $|\exp(iz^2)| = \exp(-R^2\sin(2t))$. Using $\sin(2t) \geq \frac{4}{\pi}t$ (which I dont understand how that is true), for any $t \in [0, \pi/4]$, it yields that
$$|\exp(iz^2)| \leq \exp\left(-R^2\frac{4}{\pi}t\right).$$
From here, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_\beta e^{iz^2}\,dz\right|&=\left|\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{i(Re^{i\phi})^2}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|\\\\
&=\left|\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{iR^2e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|\\\\
&=\left|\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{iR^2\cos(2\phi)}e^{-R^2\sin(2\phi)}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|\\\\
&\le R\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-(4R^2/\pi)\phi}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

where we used the triangle inequality along with the estimate $ \sin(2\phi)\ge \frac{4\phi}\pi$ for $0\le \phi\le \pi/4$.

And now you can finish.

Comment: Right, I understand now. However, I'm still wondering why $\sin(2\phi) \leq \frac{4\phi}{\pi}$. Could you please explain that?

Comment: @VicRyan graph the functions and it will be obvious. If you want it to be formal, then $\sin 2x$ is concave on $[0,\pi/4]$ and so lies above the straight line connecting both ends. Note that it should be $\sin(2\phi)\geq \dfrac{4\phi}{\pi}.$

Comment: @dezdichado Yes of course.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @vicryan I inadvertently had the inequality backwards.  To see that $\sin(2x)\ge 4x/\pi$, let $f(x) =\sin(2x)-4x/\pi$. Note  $f(0)=f(\pi/4)=0$ and $f''(x)=-4\sin(2x)\le 0$. What can you deduce about the sign of $f(x)$